# Turning .html templates into AMD modules with grunt-ts

Tags: typescript, grunt-ts

Using `grunt-ts` with say the `html: ["*.tpl.html"]` option, it compiles `*.tpl.html` files in the end into `*.tpl.html.js` files, which set a global `var`.

Can I instead tell `grunt-ts` to output the final `.js` file in a different module syntax, such as AMD or CommonJS, (to avoid using globals)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can I instead tell grunt-ts to output the final .js file in a different module syntax, such as AMD or CommonJS, (to avoid using globals)

Not at the moment. The whole html template mechanism was written before module systems exploded in popularity.